# applet in Java7 not working after signing jar

Tags: java, jar, sign, signed-applet

We used to have an applet in an Alfresco application which was build and compiled in Java 6. since our systems needed to update to Java7 JVM the applet launch started to show all those anoying security messages and it was quite a pain for our users.

We readed the guideness of Java7 and it seems that we just needed to sign our jars involved in the applet with CA certificate. We did so and now all our jars are signed with the certificate correctly following the Java 7 guide and using Keystore tool. However we have found two issues now with all the applets that invoke these signed jars (for this example I am gonna show only one of our applets)

1) Applets take a lot now to load (before signing and in Java6 JVM used to take 15 secs and now we are talking about minutes!!!).

2) We find the ClassNotfoundException issue that avoids our applets to work.

Most important problem for us is the second issue "ClassNotFoundException" as after spending days reading about possible solutions we are not able to get it to work.

Our applet is in a jsp page inserted like this code

```
<applet code="uk.co.mmscomputing.application.imageviewer.MainApp.class" 
        codebase="<%= scan.getUrlAlfrescoApplet() %>" 
        archive="scan-plugin-mmsc_v1.2.jar, alfresco-web-service-client.jar, jai_core.jar, jai_codec.jar, activation.jar, alfresco-core.jar, axis-1.4.jar, bcprov-jdk15-137.jar, commons-discovery-0.2.jar, commons-logging-1.1.jar, jaxrpc.jar, mail.jar, opensaml-1.0.1.jar, saaj.jar, wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar, wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar, wss4j.jar, xalan.jar, xercesImpl-2.8.0.jar, xmlsec-1.4.1.jar" 
        width="100%" height="600" name="Veritas Scan">
        <PARAM name="scanFile" value="<%= scan.getFileName() %>">
        <PARAM name="container" value="<%= scan.getSpaceNodeRef().getId() %>">
        <PARAM name="multipage" value="<%= scan.getFactMultipage() %>">
        <PARAM name="urlAlfrescoWS" value="<%= scan.getUrlAlfrescoWS() %>">
        <PARAM name="ocr" value="<%= scan.getOcr() %>">
        <PARAM name="cif" value="<%= scan.getCIF() %>">
        <PARAM name="user" value="<%= scan.getUserName() %>">
        <PARAM name="ticket" value="<%= scan.getTicket() %>">
        <PARAM name="sessionId" value="<%= scan.getSessionId() %>">
        <PARAM name="java_arguments" value="-Xmx256m">
        <PARAM name="java_version" value="1.6*">
        <PARAM name="separate_jvm" value="true">
        Your browser does not support the <code>applet</code> tag.
     </applet>
```

and the jars signed are in

tomcat/alfresco/applets

However when we try to launch this applet in its jsp page at the end we get this error message:

ClassNotFoundException

uk.co.mmscomputing.application.imageviewer.MainApp.class

What we see in the java console is this:

```
 Java Plugin 10.55.2.13
Usando versión de JRE 1.7.0_55-b13 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
Directorio de inicio del usuario = C:\Documents and Settings\Dolores Sanguinetti
----------------------------------------------------
c:   borrar ventana de consola
f:   finalizar objetos en la cola de finalización
g:   recopilación de basura
h:   mostrar este mensaje de ayuda
l:   volcar lista de classloader
m:   imprimir uso de memoria
o:   disparar registro
q:   ocultar consola
r:   recargar configuración de política
s:   volcar propiedades del sistema y de despliegue
t:   volcar lista de threads
v:   volcar pila de threads
x:   borrar caché de classloader
0-5: definir nivel de rastreo en <n>
----------------------------------------------------
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/scan-plugin-mmsc_v1.2.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Thu Jun 16 11:51:52 CEST 2011,length=6280199
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/scan-plugin-mmsc_v1.2.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Thu Jun 16 11:51:52 CEST 2011,length=6280199
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/alfresco-web-service-client.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:51:54 CET 2013,length=418382
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/alfresco-web-service-client.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:51:54 CET 2013,length=418382
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/jai_core.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Oct 01 12:17:30 CEST 2010,length=1966212
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/jai_core.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Oct 01 12:17:30 CEST 2010,length=1966212
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/jai_codec.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Oct 01 12:17:30 CEST 2010,length=267173
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/jai_codec.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Oct 01 12:17:30 CEST 2010,length=267173
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/activation.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Mon May 05 23:35:34 CEST 2014,length=59420
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/activation.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Mon May 05 23:35:34 CEST 2014,length=59420
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/alfresco-core.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:51:39 CET 2013,length=173167
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/alfresco-core.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:51:39 CET 2013,length=173167
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/axis-1.4.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:52:13 CET 2013,length=1689344
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/axis-1.4.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:52:13 CET 2013,length=1689344
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/bcprov-jdk15-137.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Oct 01 12:17:26 CEST 2010,length=1528841
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/bcprov-jdk15-137.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Oct 01 12:17:26 CEST 2010,length=1528841
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/commons-discovery-0.2.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:53:01 CET 2013,length=79805
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/commons-discovery-0.2.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:53:01 CET 2013,length=79805
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/commons-logging-1.1.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:53:15 CET 2013,length=58414
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/commons-logging-1.1.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:53:15 CET 2013,length=58414
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/jaxrpc.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:53:40 CET 2013,length=39674
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/jaxrpc.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:53:40 CET 2013,length=39674
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/mail.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:55:43 CET 2013,length=364719
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/mail.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:55:43 CET 2013,length=364719
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/opensaml-1.0.1.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:55:02 CET 2013,length=112773
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/opensaml-1.0.1.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:55:02 CET 2013,length=112773
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/saaj.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Oct 01 12:17:28 CEST 2010,length=22324
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/saaj.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Oct 01 12:17:28 CEST 2010,length=22324
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Oct 01 12:17:28 CEST 2010,length=136990
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Oct 01 12:17:28 CEST 2010,length=136990
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:54:19 CET 2013,length=165762
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:54:19 CET 2013,length=165762
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/wss4j.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:54:41 CET 2013,length=323332
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/wss4j.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:54:41 CET 2013,length=323332
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/xalan.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Oct 01 12:17:28 CEST 2010,length=3175437
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/xalan.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Oct 01 12:17:28 CEST 2010,length=3175437
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/xercesImpl-2.8.0.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Oct 01 12:17:28 CEST 2010,length=1280498
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/xercesImpl-2.8.0.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Oct 01 12:17:28 CEST 2010,length=1280498
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/xmlsec-1.4.1.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:55:23 CET 2013,length=455842
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/xmlsec-1.4.1.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:55:23 CET 2013,length=455842
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/scan-plugin-mmsc_v1.2.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Thu Jun 16 11:51:52 CEST 2011,length=6280199
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/scan-plugin-mmsc_v1.2.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Thu Jun 16 11:51:52 CEST 2011,length=6280199
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/alfresco-web-service-client.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:51:54 CET 2013,length=418382
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/alfresco-web-service-client.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:51:54 CET 2013,length=418382
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/jai_core.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Oct 01 12:17:30 CEST 2010,length=1966212
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/jai_core.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Oct 01 12:17:30 CEST 2010,length=1966212
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/jai_codec.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Oct 01 12:17:30 CEST 2010,length=267173
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/jai_codec.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Oct 01 12:17:30 CEST 2010,length=267173
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/activation.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Mon May 05 23:35:34 CEST 2014,length=59420
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/activation.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Mon May 05 23:35:34 CEST 2014,length=59420
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/alfresco-core.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:51:39 CET 2013,length=173167
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/alfresco-core.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:51:39 CET 2013,length=173167
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/axis-1.4.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:52:13 CET 2013,length=1689344
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/axis-1.4.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:52:13 CET 2013,length=1689344
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/bcprov-jdk15-137.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Oct 01 12:17:26 CEST 2010,length=1528841
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/bcprov-jdk15-137.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Oct 01 12:17:26 CEST 2010,length=1528841
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/commons-discovery-0.2.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:53:01 CET 2013,length=79805
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/commons-discovery-0.2.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:53:01 CET 2013,length=79805
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/commons-logging-1.1.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:53:15 CET 2013,length=58414
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/commons-logging-1.1.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:53:15 CET 2013,length=58414
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/jaxrpc.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:53:40 CET 2013,length=39674
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/jaxrpc.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:53:40 CET 2013,length=39674
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/mail.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:55:43 CET 2013,length=364719
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/mail.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:55:43 CET 2013,length=364719
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/opensaml-1.0.1.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:55:02 CET 2013,length=112773
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/opensaml-1.0.1.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:55:02 CET 2013,length=112773
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/saaj.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Oct 01 12:17:28 CEST 2010,length=22324
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/saaj.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Oct 01 12:17:28 CEST 2010,length=22324
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Oct 01 12:17:28 CEST 2010,length=136990
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Oct 01 12:17:28 CEST 2010,length=136990
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:54:19 CET 2013,length=165762
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:54:19 CET 2013,length=165762
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/wss4j.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:54:41 CET 2013,length=323332
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/wss4j.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:54:41 CET 2013,length=323332
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/xalan.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Oct 01 12:17:28 CEST 2010,length=3175437
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/xalan.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Oct 01 12:17:28 CEST 2010,length=3175437
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/xercesImpl-2.8.0.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Oct 01 12:17:28 CEST 2010,length=1280498
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/xercesImpl-2.8.0.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Oct 01 12:17:28 CEST 2010,length=1280498
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/xmlsec-1.4.1.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:55:23 CET 2013,length=455842
CacheEntry[http://IP_SERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/xmlsec-1.4.1.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Fri Nov 29 12:55:23 CET 2013,length=455842
```

Any ideas about how can we get our applets back and running smoothly in Java7???
We need this so badly :-(.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you turned trace on? This will show you more information in the Java console.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for giving us this suggestion, We have set the trace mode on in java console and this is what we got. Still dont know why the Class is not being found.

Please do you see anything that we must fix. Also dont know exactly why we get the message for the jars saying

```
network: URL http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/scan-plugin-mmsc_v1.2.jar escrita en archivo C:\Documents and Settings\Dolores Sanguinetti\Configuración local\Datos de programa\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\43\e97acab-2f09d0d9-temp
java.lang.SecurityException: invalid SHA1 signature file digest for uk/co/mmscomputing/imageio/tiff/TIFFBaselineFactory.class
```

Thanks a lot

```
Java Plugin 10.55.2.13
Usando versión de JRE 1.7.0_55-b13 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
Directorio de inicio del usuario = C:\Documents and Settings\Dolores Sanguinetti
----------------------------------------------------
c:   borrar ventana de consola
f:   finalizar objetos en la cola de finalización
g:   recopilación de basura
h:   mostrar este mensaje de ayuda
l:   volcar lista de classloader
m:   imprimir uso de memoria
o:   disparar registro
q:   ocultar consola
r:   recargar configuración de política
s:   volcar propiedades del sistema y de despliegue
t:   volcar lista de threads
v:   volcar pila de threads
x:   borrar caché de classloader
0-5: definir nivel de rastreo en <n>
----------------------------------------------------
cache: Initialize resource manager: com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl@52d654
security:  --- parseCommandLine converted : -Xmx256m
into:
[-Xmx256m]
basic: Listener de progreso agregado: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@157e563
security: Expected Main URL: http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/scan-plugin-mmsc_v1.2.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/scan-plugin-mmsc_v1.2.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/alfresco-web-service-client.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/jai_core.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/jai_codec.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/activation.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/alfresco-core.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/axis-1.4.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/bcprov-jdk15-137.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/commons-discovery-0.2.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/commons-logging-1.1.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/jaxrpc.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/mail.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/opensaml-1.0.1.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/saaj.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/wss4j.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/xalan.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/xercesImpl-2.8.0.jar
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/xmlsec-1.4.1.jar
security: Se ha activado la comprobación de revocación de la lista negra
security: blacklist: created: NEED_LOAD, lastModified: 1399304647198
security: blacklist: hasBeenModifiedSince 1399304764792 (we have 1399304647198)
security: Está activada la comprobación de lista de bibliotecas de confianza
network: Se ha encontrado la entrada de caché [URL: http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/scan-plugin-mmsc_v1.2.jar, versión: null] prevalidated=false/0
cache: Adding MemoryCache entry: http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/scan-plugin-mmsc_v1.2.jar
cache: Resource http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/scan-plugin-mmsc_v1.2.jar has expired.
network: Conectando http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/scan-plugin-mmsc_v1.2.jar con proxy=DIRECT
network: Conectando http://54.217.234.34:8080/ con proxy=DIRECT
network: ResponseCode de http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/scan-plugin-mmsc_v1.2.jar: 200
network: Codificación de http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/scan-plugin-mmsc_v1.2.jar: null
network: Desconectar conexión con http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/scan-plugin-mmsc_v1.2.jar
CacheEntry[http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/scan-plugin-mmsc_v1.2.jar]: updateAvailable=true,lastModified=Thu Jun 16 11:51:52 CEST 2011,length=6280199
network: Conectando http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/scan-plugin-mmsc_v1.2.jar con proxy=DIRECT
network: Conectando http://54.217.234.34:8080/ con proxy=DIRECT
network: Descargando recurso: http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/scan-plugin-mmsc_v1.2.jar
    Content-Lenght: 6.318.795
    Content-Encoding: null
security: blacklist: hasBeenModifiedSince 1399304999901 (we have 1399304647198)
security: blacklist: hasBeenModifiedSince 1399305004823 (we have 1399304647198)
security: blacklist: hasBeenModifiedSince 1399305002104 (we have 1399304647198)
security: blacklist: hasBeenModifiedSince 1399305009260 (we have 1399304647198)
security: blacklist: hasBeenModifiedSince 1399305007979 (we have 1399304647198)
security: blacklist: hasBeenModifiedSince 1399304990823 (we have 1399304647198)
security: blacklist: hasBeenModifiedSince 1399304995401 (we have 1399304647198)
security: blacklist: hasBeenModifiedSince 1399304988463 (we have 1399304647198)
security: blacklist: hasBeenModifiedSince 1399305011088 (we have 1399304647198)
security: blacklist: hasBeenModifiedSince 1399326351562 (we have 1399304647198)
security: blacklist: hasBeenModifiedSince 1399304764792 (we have 1399304647198)
security: blacklist: hasBeenModifiedSince 1399305006260 (we have 1399304647198)
security: blacklist: hasBeenModifiedSince 1399304647307 (we have 1399304647198)
security: blacklist: hasBeenModifiedSince 1399304967057 (we have 1399304647198)
security: blacklist: hasBeenModifiedSince 1399305002823 (we have 1399304647198)
security: blacklist: hasBeenModifiedSince 1399304982979 (we have 1399304647198)
security: blacklist: hasBeenModifiedSince 1399305022260 (we have 1399304647198)
security: blacklist: hasBeenModifiedSince 1399305024401 (we have 1399304647198)
security: blacklist: hasBeenModifiedSince 1399305001026 (we have 1399304647198)
security: blacklist: hasBeenModifiedSince 1399305006807 (we have 1399304647198)
security: blacklist: hasBeenModifiedSince 1399305017995 (we have 1399304647198)
network: CleanupThread utilizado 120363 us
network: URL http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/scan-plugin-mmsc_v1.2.jar escrita en archivo C:\Documents and Settings\Dolores Sanguinetti\Configuración local\Datos de programa\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\43\e97acab-2f09d0d9-temp
java.lang.SecurityException: invalid SHA1 signature file digest for uk/co/mmscomputing/imageio/tiff/TIFFBaselineFactory.class
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.verifySection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.ensureInitialization(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getCodeSources(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JavaUtilJarAccessImpl.getCodeSources(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.EnhancedJarVerifier.validate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry.processJar(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry.access$2200(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry$10.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry.writeFileToDisk(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.CacheEntry.writeFileToDisk(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.Cache$6.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.Cache.downloadResourceToCache(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.cache.DeployFileOutputStream.close(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.close(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.close(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.downloadJAR(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.retrieve(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.retrieve(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.getJarFileInternal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.access$1000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
network: Eliminar entrada de caché: http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/scan-plugin-mmsc_v1.2.jar
cache: MemoryCache: removed entry http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/scan-plugin-mmsc_v1.2.jar
network: CleanupThread utilizado 2 us


......
......
.....
......
......
......
......
......
......
......



network: No se ha encontrado la entrada de caché [URL: http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/uk/co/mmscomputing/application/imageviewer/MainApp.class, versión: null]
network: Conectando http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/uk/co/mmscomputing/application/imageviewer/MainApp.class con proxy=DIRECT
network: No se ha encontrado la entrada de caché [URL: http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/uk/co/mmscomputing/application/imageviewer/MainApp/class.class, versión: null]
network: Conectando http://IPSERVER:8080/alfresco/applets/uk/co/mmscomputing/application/imageviewer/MainApp/class.class con proxy=DIRECT
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: uk.co.mmscomputing.application.imageviewer.MainApp.class
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
basic: cargar: clase uk.co.mmscomputing.application.imageviewer.MainApp.class no encontrada.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: uk.co.mmscomputing.application.imageviewer.MainApp.class
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Ignored exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: uk.co.mmscomputing.application.imageviewer.MainApp.class
basic: Dialog type is not candidate for embedding
basic: Listener de progreso eliminado: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@157e563
security: Accediendo a las claves y el certificado del perfil de usuario de Mozilla: null
security: Restablecer el almacén de certificados de sesión denegados
```